# KnockoutJS 'checked' binding not applied in customBinding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a checkbox being controller by a Knockout observable, but in a custom binding, the element is not checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked, highlightIfChecked: 'test'"/>
```

The element is checked and unchecked on the page, but in the `highlightIfChecked` custom binding, it is not. I'm using `$(elem).is(":checked")`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JgLck/

**How can I get the element to be checked in the custom binding?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting of the element's checked value happens in the `checked` binding's `update` function.  Currently, all of the `init` functions run before the `update` functions for the bindings on an element.

So, if you switched your custom binding to use `update` instead of `init`, then you would see the right value.

Also, you would need to change your `isChecked` value into an observable, if you want the binding to trigger again.  Note that in KO 3.0, bindings will be processed independently, so your custom binding would need to access `isChecked` to create a dependency.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/eXEmM/

Comment: Apologies; the lack of an observable on `isChecked` is an oversight in this simplified example. If bindings will be processed independently, how will the `element` parameter look? Would it still give correct results when using `$(element).is("checked")`?

Comment: yes, it would still give you the correct value for the current state of the element. It would depend on whether your the `checked` binding has already updated the element though. Depending on your need, you can always access the observable directly (`isChecked`).